# The index that I have created for a table does not work

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE cities 
(
    id serial, 
    name character varying(30)
);
```

Then, some rows were added. In order to make the queries faster, an index was defined:

```
CREATE INDEX cities_name_idx ON cities (name);
SET enable_seqscan TO off;
```

However, after running EXPLAIN for this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM cities 
WHERE name ILIKE 'Lond%'
```

The result was: it turned out that the index isn't used – the database performs a sequential scan instead.

Why is it happening and how to fix it?

Comment: How many records in your table? If there aren't enough, the index will be ignored since the table scan can be faster

Comment: `ILIKE` would only work with a trigram index. Use the trick with `lower()` instead or use `citext`. Don't forget that you have to use the `text_pattern_ops` operator class in the index definition if the index is supposed to support `LIKE`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to support `ILIKE`, there is only a GIN trigram index:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pg_trgm;

CREATE INDEX ON cities USING gin (name gin_trgm_ops);
```

However, such an index tends to be big and costs a lot of performance during data modifications.

---

It would be better to change your query to

```
SELECT * FROM cities WHERE lower(name) LIKE lower('Lond%');
```

Then you could do with a regular b-tree index:

```
CREATE INDEX ON cities (name text_pattern_ops);
```

Comment: Can you point out the documentation about `text_pattern_ops`? I found [11.10. Operator Classes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-opclass.html) but it doesn't clearly mention the relationship between this operator class and the `ILIKE` operator.

Comment: @TheImpaler You found the correct documentation. That has nothing to do with `ILIKE`, it is needed to support `LIKE`. If you read [the article I wrote about it recently](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/indexing-like-postgresql-oracle/), it should become clear to you.

Comment: Excellent article, Laurenz. I'm in the process of migrating a few demanding apps towards PostgreSQL (Aurora flavor) and this article can come in handy. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a functional index. For example:

```
create index ix1 on cities ((lower(name)));

select * 
from cities 
where lower(name) >= lower('Lond') and lower(name) < lower('Lone')
```

Or, alternatively, sometimes it's possible to change a case insensitive collation for the column.

Comment: You are missing the `text_pattern_ops` operator class. Besides, case insensitive collations won't work with pattern matching.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Ah, didn't know that. Changed the solution. Maybe this one will use an index range scan.